# Is there an issue with the Infura provider project ID or the promise?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, ethereum, solidity

I'm following [these](https://blog.coinbase.com/introduction-to-building-on-defi-with-ethereum-and-usdc-part-1-ea952295a6e2) [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5owMYFIoRZQ) and when I get to the getTestnetUSDC.js part, the code executes through console logging the mnemonic and address, and then throws the below error.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit (error={"reason":"cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit","code":"UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT","method":"estimateGas","transaction":{"from":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","gasPrice":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x04a817c800"},"to":"0x11111111111111111111111111111111111","data":"0xb09bd39a"}}, tx={"data":"0xb09bd39a","to":{},"gasPrice":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x04a817c800"},"from":"0x7C417b3dd2810e6a6aFCBa5bDE60dc122EeA1403","nonce":{},"gasLimit":{},"chainId":{}}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=abstract-signer/5.0.13)
at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\Ethereum\dapps\ethersjs-tutorial\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:179:21)
at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\Ethereum\dapps\ethersjs-tutorial\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:188:20)
at C:\Users\Ethereum\dapps\ethersjs-tutorial\node_modules\@ethersproject\abstract-signer\lib\index.js:260:47
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async Promise.all (index 5)

(node:21020) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag --unhandled-rejections=strict (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1) (node:21020) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

After modifying

```
    const tx = await usdc.gimmeSome({ gasPrice: 20e9 });
```

to

```
const tx = await usdc.gimmeSome({ gasPrice: 20e9, gasLimit: 20e9 });
```

I get the below error.

```
(node:30368) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: bad response (status=401, headers={"date":"Sun, 21 Feb 2021 04:12:08 GMT","content-type":"text/plain; charset=utf-8","content-length":"31","connection":"close","vary":"Origin","www-authenticate":"Basic realm=\"Project ID is required in the URL\"","x-content-type-options":"nosniff"}, body="project id required in the url\n", requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_sendRawTransaction\",\"params\":[\"0xf86b808504a817c8008504a817c8009468ec573c119826db2eaea1efbfc2970cdac869c48084b09bd39a29a0765855d66c1c5d3704293c161664fb2ea449a5e00601e5c16cd34b0b82fb6ceea0627d10d4732b9fe4cbe549b179bfb69d1de43dad371f95916b1ada637426dad8\"],\"id\":42,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}", requestMethod="POST", url="https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/11111111111111111111111111111111", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.0.13)
at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\Ethereum\dapps\ethersjs-tutorial\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:179:21)
at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\Ethereum\dapps\ethersjs-tutorial\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:188:20)
at C:\Users\Ethereum\dapps\ethersjs-tutorial\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:227:36
at step (C:\Users\Ethereum\dapps\ethersjs-tutorial\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:33:23)
at Object.next (C:\Users\Ethereum\dapps\ethersjs-tutorial\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:14:53)
at fulfilled (C:\Users\Ethereum\dapps\ethersjs-tutorial\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:5:58)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

(node:30368) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1) (node:30368) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

P.S.: I changed the addresses and IDs for the purposes of asking this question.

Comment: The sentence starting "This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function ... " tells you all you need to know.